# Why is the result of this calculation 0 and not 1?

Tags: texturing, mathematics

Why is the result of this calculation 0 and not 1?

[image]

Comment: My quess is that somehow your value ends up 0.999999 and floor rounds it down to 0, but I would like to know why as well

Comment: If you switch to cycles and set the shading mode to 'rendered' it works as expected. I guess it's a current limitation of Eevee...? Not sure. Otherwise might worth to file a bug report.

Comment: I tried to recreate it and it shows black in both eevee and cycles

Comment: I got the same result as @brockmann - it shows white in Cycles, but black in Eevee. The problem seems to be the *Floor* node. If I mute it, the result is white in Eevee, too. If I render it without *Floor* and check the RGB values in the render result, they are all 1.0000 which should be white with *Floor* as well. Maybe there is a floating point issue and somehow it is 0.9999999... instead of 1 or it's a bug in Eevee. Also if I set the value to 10.000001 which is shown as 10.000 it works in Eevee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by [accuracy problems of floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems). Those problems [typically?] don't occur with small whole numbers like `10.0`, as you can see for yourself here:

[IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

You can also test your node setup by disconnecting *Math > Modulo* and inputting `10.0` manually as the first *Value* of the *Math > Divide* node. This shows the problem happens inside the modulo node.

I'm not well versed in the Blender source arcane, but it seems the source of that node is in [COM_MathBaseOperation.cpp](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/compositor/operations/COM_MathBaseOperation.cpp#L423)

```
void MathModuloOperation::executePixelSampled(float output[4],
                                              float x,
                                              float y,
                                              PixelSampler sampler)
{
  float inputValue1[4];
  float inputValue2[4];

  this->m_inputValue1Operation->readSampled(inputValue1, x, y, sampler);
  this->m_inputValue2Operation->readSampled(inputValue2, x, y, sampler);

  if (inputValue2[0] == 0) {
    output[0] = 0.0;
  }
  else {
    output[0] = fmod(inputValue1[0], inputValue2[0]);
  }

  clampIfNeeded(output);
}
```

However, when I try to `fmod(10.0, 100.0)` in C++:

```
float numer = 10.0, denom = 100.0;
float modded = fmod(numer, denom);
float floored = floor(modded);
```

I get correct results:

[image]

So I suspect that behind the scenes, the numbers aren't evaluated as presented in the node setup. Perhaps they are scaled down for some reason?

```
float numer = 0.01, denom = 0.1;
float modded = fmod(numer, denom);
```

[image]

Just a guess here.

I think in order to stay sane, you should always assume that your number may randomly increase or decrease by the smallest possible step at any point, so think of it as randomly increasing/decreasing by `0.00000001` and work around that.

**As a bonus**, try to set your divisor in the *Math > Divide* node to `9.999999`. Once you test it and see you get a white material, click on the value, change nothing, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Perhaps a small anecdote, I remember when I wrote a shader in Adobe Flash AGAL and a comparison with a number worked as expected on my desktop GPU, but failed in the CPU emulation mode on my old laptop. Just an anecdotal evidence to support my second last paragraph.

Comment: nope the result is 10... I just checked within blender.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a brain fade yesterday and was proposing a nonsensical argument.  I'm going to delete my comments.

Comment: @MartyFouts no problem, cheers!